# How to inject dependencies into resources with Jersey?

Tags: rest, dependency-injection, jersey, jax-rs

I'm having the following code:

```
@Path("stores")
class StoreResources {

  private ServerConfig config;

  @GET
  public String getAll() {
   //do some stuff with ServerConfig
  }
}
```

And I need the `ServerConfig` object to be injected into this class from outside and use it inside the `getAll()` method.

What are the possible ways to achieve it? Should I use a DI framework like Guice or Spring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good blog about Spring injection under Jersey http://javaswamy.blogspot.com/2010/01/making-jersey-work-with-spring.html

The upshot is you use annotations to flag fields that are to be injected, an example resource being

```
package com.km.services;  

import javax.ws.rs.GET;  
import javax.ws.rs.Path;  
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;  
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;  
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;  
import com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Inject;  
import com.km.spring.SimpleBean;  

@Path("/hello")  
@Component  
@Scope("request")  
public class HelloResource {  

   @Inject private SimpleBean simpleBean;  

   @GET  
   @Produces("text/plain")  
   public String getMessage() {  
    return simpleBean.sayHello();  
   }  
}
```

For my purposes the configuration was excessively difficult so I used a static spring resolver factory to resolve the bean. eg.

```
private SimpleBean simpleBean = SpringBeanFactory.getBean("mySimpleBean");
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Spring or Guice to inject a ServletConfig. Jersey does through its own injection mechanism. Refer to the simple-servlet example that comes with Jersey samples distribution. Here is the sample code that injects a HttpServletRequest and a ServletConfig onto a resource:

```
@Path("/resource1")
public class ResourceBean1 {

    @Context
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    @Context
    ServletConfig servletConfig;

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String describe() {
        return "Hello World from resource 1 in servlet: '" +
                servletConfig.getServletName() +
                "', path: '" +
                servletRequest.getServletPath() +
                "'";
    }

}
```

When deploying an JAX-RS application using Servlet then ServletConfig, ServletContext, HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse are available for injection using @Context.

Comment: It's not a `ServletConfig`, it's a `ServerConfig`, which is probably a custom object that he wants to be injected.